# How do you delete a generated mdf file with open connections?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have created a database with this code:

```
public static void CreateDatabase(string databasePath)
{
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", databasePath);

        using (var connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=master; Integrated Security=true;;"))
        {
            connection.Open();

            using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText =
                    String.Format("CREATE DATABASE {0} ON PRIMARY (NAME={0}, FILENAME='{1}')", "CoolDatabase", databasePath + @"\database.mdf");
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                command.CommandText =
                    String.Format("EXEC sp_detach_db '{0}', 'true'", "CotanDB");
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            connection.Close();
        }
}
```

Which creates a nice working `.mdf` file for my unit tests. However, after running all tests on it, I want to remove it again so it doesn't take up space.

I tried this:

```
    public static void DestroyDatabase(string databasePath)
    {
        if (File.Exists(databasePath + @"\database.mdf"))
        {
            File.Delete(databasePath + @"\database.mdf");
        }

        if (File.Exists(databasePath + @"\database_log.ldf"))
        {
            File.Delete(databasePath + @"\database_log.ldf");
        }
    }
```

But that throws an error

> The process cannot access the file 'path to the database\database.mdf'
>   because it is being used by another process.

So I tried to close all connections to my database so I could drop it and delete the file. However, this does not work:

```
var server = new Server();
server.KillDatabase(databasePath + @"\database.mdf");
```

Which throws

> Failed to connect to server ..

How do I destroy my local database file?

Edit: I tried the code in the answer in the comments:

```
 using (var connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=master; Integrated Security=true;;"))
        {
            connection.Open();

            using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText =
                    String.Format("USE master");
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                command.CommandText =
                    String.Format("ALTER DATABASE {0} SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE", "CotanDB");
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                command.CommandText =
                    String.Format("DROP DATABASE {0}", "CoolDatabase");
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            connection.Close();
        }
```

Followed by the same File.Delete code. But this throws:

> User does not have permission to alter database "CoolDatabase", the
>   database does not exist, or the database is not in a state that allows
>   access checks.

Comment: OFFLINE it then DROP => [How to force drop database in SQL Server 2008](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34264/how-to-force-drop-database-in-sql-server-2008/34265)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Figured it out myself. If you call SqlConnection.ClearPool(connection), all connections to your mdf file are dropped, after which you can easily delete it.</s>

Looking back at this, this is a horrible solution and should be avoided, as this construction means your unit tests are now dependent on an external database. Good luck trying to run this in an Azure Pipeline.

If you have the option, use an EntityFramework InMemory database:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/in-memory/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli